# How to align both the Text and the labelText in the TextFormField in center vertically and without affecting the border?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

If you notice the below image, both the label and the text is aligned to top.

1. Can any one help with what has to be done to make the alignment to centre these two vertically?

[image: Sample Image]

2. Also if you notice just above the 'Email' the border is cut. Could some one help with code snippet to avoid this?
3. Also is there any way, can we format based on the content(value) of the 'TextFormField'?

The following are the coding which produces the above images.

```
TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
    fillColor: Colors.white,
    filled: true,
    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
    labelText: 'Email:',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, height: 3),
    prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
    enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.white, width: 1.0)),
    focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 2.0)),
    prefixStyle: TextStyle(
      inherit: true,
      color: Colors.red,
    ),
 ),
```

Ideally I wanted a text box like the below one

[image]

Comment: Hi @Karpal, did you even manage this to work? I got exactly the same requirement.

Comment: Hi @JohanWalhout, yes, There are two types of text fields. Filled Text Field and Outlined Text field. you can use UnderlineInputBorder instead of OutlineInputBorder to set the text field as Filled Text field. The UnderlineInputBorder with zero border size will help to you to achieve this. You can wrap this with a dummy Widget to create outside border.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter allows two types of Edit Input.

1. Filled Text Field (if the border uses UnderlineInputBorder)
2. Outlined Text Field (if the border uses OutlineInputBorder)

The following code snippet helped me to fix the issue.

```
   Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
      child: TextFormField(
         decoration: const InputDecoration(
            fillColor: Colors.white,
            filled: true,
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            labelText: 'Email:',
            labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red, height: 1),
            prefixIcon: Icon(Icons.email_outlined),
            enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
            focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                     borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
            prefixStyle: TextStyle(
               inherit: true,
               color: Colors.red,
            ),
         ),
      ),
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is ok just remove the "height" parameter from labelStyle

```
labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. However I do not want the label to overlap on the border. is there a way to do that? Also, is there a way to change the property based on the content of TextFormField widget?

Comment: If you don't want to show the label on the top border then you need to remove "labelText" and you can use "hintText" Instead of the "labelText"

Comment: I wanted to show the labelText, but just below the border and align both the labelText the text accordingly and without the border being cut.